# Google Apps-Script Issue with Server-side \ Client-side HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to create a simple webapp to track daily foods I consume and fail to deliver the simple task of displaying the items from the google spreadsheet on the webapp.

On the code.js server-side everything's seem to work well as the return statement variable includes the required array data.

On the index.html client side, on the other hand, a null value to passed for a reason I can't find.

Did anyone encounter this phenomena?

I’ve used try-catch with logs and used the execution log to get to my current analysis of the issue. Full code of the code.js and index.html is below:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
    <title>Food Diary</title>
    <!-- Add some CSS for styling -->
   <!-- CSS Styling for Success Message -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
        /* Existing styles */

        /* Responsive styles for mobile devices */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {
          font-size: 32px; /* Larger font size for readability */
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 48px; /* Adjust heading size */
        }
        form {
          width: 90%; /* Use percentage for width */
          margin: auto; /* Center the form */
        }
        button {
          padding: 20px 40px; /* Larger buttons for touch screens */
      }
    /* Other responsive adjustments */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Food Tracker</h1>
    <form id="foodForm">
      <!-- Combo-box for Food/Drink Items -->
      <select name="foodItem" required>
        <option value="">Choose from list</option>
      </select>

      <!-- Quantity Input -->
      <input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity" required>

      <!-- Submission Button -->
      <button type="button" onclick="submitEntry()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Container for Success Messages -->
    <div id="messageContainer"></div>
    <div id="allEntries">
      <h3>All Entries</h3>
      <!-- Records will be listed here -->
    </div>

    <div id="todaysEntries">
      <h3>Today's Entries</h3>
      <!-- Entries will be listed here -->
    </div>

  <script>

    function handleError(error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    // Display a more detailed error message on the page
    const container = document.getElementById('todaysEntries');
    container.textContent = 'Error loading entries: ' + error.message;
    }

    function getAllEntries() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DailyTrack");
    return sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    }

    function displayAllEntries(entries) {
    const container = document.getElementById('allEntries');
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = `Item: ${entry[0]}, Date: ${entry[1]}, Quantity: ${entry[2]}`;
        container.appendChild(div);
      });
    }


    // Function to populate the combo-box with items from Google Sheets
    function populateFoodItems(items) {
        var select = document.getElementsByName("foodItem")[0];
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = option.textContent = item;
            select.appendChild(option);
        });
    }

    function displayTodaysEntries(entries) {
    
    console.log("Entries received:", entries); // This line logs the data to the console

    //Check if entries is not null or undefined
    if (!entries) {
        console.error('No entries received');
        return;
    }

    const container = document.getElementById('todaysEntries');
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = `Item: ${entry[0]}, Quantity: ${entry[2]}`; // Adjust according to your data structure
        container.appendChild(div);
    });
   }


  function submitEntry() {
    var foodItem = document.getElementsByName("foodItem")[0].value;
    var quantity = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[0].value;

    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function() {
            displaySuccessMessage(foodItem, quantity);
        })
        .addEntry(foodItem, quantity);
}

function displaySuccessMessage(foodItem, quantity) {
    var messageContainer = document.getElementById('messageContainer');

    // Create a new div for the message
    var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
    messageDiv.textContent = 'You have consumed ' + quantity + ' ' + foodItem;
    messageDiv.style.color = 'red'; // You can add more styling as needed

    // Append the new message div to the container
    messageContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
}

    // Load items into the combo-box when the page loads
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateFoodItems).getFoodItems();
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(displayTodaysEntries)
        .withFailureHandler(handleError)
        .getTodaysEntries();
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(displayAllEntries)
        .getAllEntries();
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**code.js**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setTitle('Food Tracker') // Optional: Set a title for your web app page
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
function addEntry(foodItem, quantity) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DailyTrack");
  sheet.appendRow([foodItem, new Date(),  quantity]);
}
function submitEntry() {
    var foodItem = document.getElementsByName("foodItem")[0].value;
    var quantity = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[0].value;

    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function() {
    displaySuccessMessage(foodItem,quantity);
    }) 
    .addEntry(foodItem, quantity);
}

// Function to display success message
function displaySuccessMessage(foodItem, quantity) {
    var messageContainer = document.getElementById('messageContainer');

    // Create a new div for the message
    var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
    messageDiv.textContent = 'You have consumed ' + quantity + ' ' + foodItem;
    messageDiv.style.color = 'red'; // You can add more styling as needed

    // Append the new message div to the container
    messageContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
}
function getEntries() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DailyTrack");
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
}
function getFoodItems() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1a04dsi8NSHP6QQY4ieidGlMoNQqINdBP6y_kPL-UGb8').getSheetByName('DataSets');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    return data.map(function(row) { return row[0]; }); // Assuming items are in the first column
}

function getTodaysEntries() {
    try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DailyTrack");
    const today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set to start of the day
    Logger.log("Today's Date (Start of Day): " + today);

    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log("Data from Spreadsheet: ");
    Logger.log(data);

    const filteredData = data.filter(row => {
        const entryDate = new Date(row[1]); // Assuming date is in the second column
        entryDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Logger.log("Entry Date: " + entryDate + ", Today: " + today + ", Comparison Result: " + (entryDate.getTime() === today.getTime()));
        return entryDate.getTime() === today.getTime();
    });
    Logger.log("Filtered Data (Today's Entries): ");
    Logger.log(filteredData);

    return filteredData;

    } catch (error) {
        Logger.log('Error in getTodaysEntries: ' + error.toString());
        throw new Error('Error fetching entries.');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just found the issue. Apparently the js Date() department creates an error when read by the Client-side js clause. I've changed the way data is saved to the spreadsheet to a string type using the "new Date().toString()" and this has resolved the issue.